# Math.max() - if more elements are max?

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, max, highest

For my quiz, I want to get the highest number of all answers. So far it works, but when there are 4 answers and 2 said A is right and two said B is right, then the overall group-result should be WRONG. So I want to find out, if there are more than only one highest elements:

example:
Math.max(1,2,3,4) ---> 4
Math.max(2,2,0,0) ---> 2 (I need to know that there are more than one highest elements)

Thanks, Marc

Comment: `Math.max` returns the maximum value, it doesn't count occurences.

Comment: You could remove all duplicates first and then do the Math.Max()

Comment: He wants to know how many duplicates there are @MortenOC. Right, Marc?

Comment: But if he removes all duplicates before the Math.Max.. he will get the max every time. Lets its. 2,1,2,2. Only 2,1 will be back, and then 2 is max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this answer I will assume you have the answers put in an Array.

You can first use this function to find the max value of the array:

```
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, array);
```

Then you can find the amount of times this value occurs by using the following:

```
array.sort();
var nrOfMaxValue = array.lastIndexOf(maxValue) - array.indexOf(maxValue);
```

Hope this works for you!

**edit**: I just figured, if you only want to know if the max answer was given more than once you can just do this, without sorting the array:

```
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, array);
var onlyOnceAnswered = array.lastIndexOf(maxValue) == array.indexOf(maxValue);
```

Comment: It's very elegant, but I wonder if it is faster than my code. For small arrays of course fully irrelevant. Much less to type. +1

Comment: this worked out best for me. I really like the onlyOnceAnswered code, its simple, but functional. thanks

Answer (score 2):

So write your own function for this, like this:

```
function maxFindAndCount(listOfNumbers) {
  var result = { max: null, count: 0 };
  result.max = Math.max(listOfNumbers);
  for (var l in listOfNumbers) {
    if (listOfNumbers[l] == result.max)
      result.count++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
var listOfNumbers = [1,2,3,4,4];
var result = maxFindAndCount(listOfNumbers);
var max = result.max;
var count = result.count;
```

Comment: Caveat: `listOfNumbers` got to be an `object` for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in. Don't say `arrays` are also `objects` in Javascript, I mean `object`.

Comment: You are wrong. It works like this (with nuances, but I guess he will not extend the array prototype and it is just much faster to type). However, if you want you can also use a classical `for` loop `for (var l = 0; l < listOfNumbers.length; l++) {...`

Comment: Array IS an enumerable type. It will just iterate over all indexes and eventually added properties. If he adds no properties to this array, it will work correctly.

Comment: Ok. Learned for today. Sunday. Holy day.

Comment: hi, very good idea, but Math.max([1,2,3,4,4]) will result in NaN, because it must not be an array. How do I solve that?

Comment: You gotta use the solution the others sported with `.apply()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Example:_Using_Math.max.

Answer (score 0):

```
function highscores(arr){
    var max= Math.max.apply(Array, arr);
    return arr.filter(function(itm){
        return itm=== max;
    });
}
```

var A= [2, 3, 4, 4];

**highscores(A)**

```
returned value: (Array)[4, 4]
```